# List similar to a ListBox

Tags: firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I'm using FireMonkey/XE8

I need a list, which items can have **two** rows and **multiple** columns of labels.

I made an image for better understanding. (grey = background, turquoise = item)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GValj.png)

I already tried using a custom listbox-style but I struggled how to adjust the label positions for different widths 
(I guess I'd have to change the style at runtime somehow)

Then somebody suggested me using a base class (like `TStyledControl`) and handle all the drawing by myself (maybe someone has an example for this?).

Is there a component that can do something like that? 
Are there other options/approaches for this?

Comment: Have a look at the Delphi 10 Seattle demos (http://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/branches/RADStudio_Seattle), specifically the ListViewMultiDetailAppearance sample under Multi-Device Samples\User Interface\ListView (sorry - can't get to SF from my work machine to get a specific link; the one I posted is from the documentation), which shows using a listview to do something similar. Make sure to look at the readme.html file carefully, as it describes installing and using the example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using a 3rd party, Woll2Woll FirePower can do this (my company's FireMonkey library). FirePower allows you to visually design your item layout at design time by dropping in and arranging controls/labels, and then bind them visually to the fields in your database or in-memory data structures. When you run your program, it will appear as a horizontal or vertical listbox based on the layout you have defined. If you would like to do this, you can download a trial of Firepower for XE8 or Seattle from http://www.woll2woll.com/trial-and-free-versions.html, and then download the following sample I prepared for you, http://downloads.woll2woll.com/samples/FPLayoutGridSample1.zip

Then open and run the project. Note that you can easily re-arrange the layout of your labels/controls in this form of listbox. This demo uses in-memory data structures to fill the list.  If you just want to run a sample executable I built which shows you this without having to install FirePower, you can download it from http://downloads.woll2woll.com/samples/PFreeFormatListBoxDemo.exe

Comment: Advertising here is only permitted in certain circumstances. If you want to write a post that explains how to do it with built-in FMX controls, and then offer your product as a simpler alternative, that's fine. Posting an answer that consists only of advertising for your product with off-site links is not.

Comment: I only commented with a 3rd party because the original question included the following at the end. "Is there a component that can do something like that? Are there other options/approaches for this?"